# Using Slider to show dowloading progress in WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, usability, marketplace

Can I use Slider to show downloading progress? What about usability, user experience and main one Market Place limitation. Or you have another idea how to show not only process, but progress to?

Comment: Why do you want to use a slider when the ProgressBar control is built for this behaviour?

Comment: If your ever have install app from market place, than you seen, the progress to indicate it is slider or, lock like it. Please give me link to example you talking about, thanks.

Comment: That is exactly what I am talking about in my answer. Edited with a reference link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The progress bar can be used in `IsIndeterminate=False` mode can give you what you're looking for. The progress is indicated using the `Value` property, which you can keep updating. See [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms612638%28v=VS.95%29.aspx).

See this [article](http://mobile.dzone.com/articles/31-days-mango-day-15-progress)